# Missing US English keyboard layout for Mac?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mac

I think I would like to use an Apple keyboard, if the layout is such that I can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd>/<kbd>X</kbd> the same way, that is, inside the terminal and the regular apps. I don't have advanced knowledge of Apple keyboards. I simply feel less irritation when using Mac-style copy-n-paste.

Somehow, when I follow the few tutorials, I do find the UK Mac layout, but nothing for the US. Can we plug in a Mac-compatible keyboard and expect it to work, straight away or with minimal configuration?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. What have you tried so far? Which tutorials? Knowing this will help us help you. :)

Comment: so a mac layout won't give mac functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that's working everywhere so far, tho I'm only an hour into the change. I was fiddling with Alt/Super settings, in the Gnome Tweaks Tool, but the simpler...

1. **`Gnome Tweaks > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options`**
2. **`Swap Left Ctrl with Left Alt`**
3. **`Desktop settings need no change`**
4. **`Adjust Terminal preferences if you like`**

Works! Pretty nice, and a relief if you're quick with something like:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> > <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> > <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in the browser to search errors, etc.

No myriad system configs to dig up, no new layouts or themes, just the handy `Gnome Tweaks` app.